# Как отменить сheckout без удаления папки?

Tags: svn

В общем вопрос наверно глупый, но не могу разобраться. Для начала скажу, что использую не консольный svn, a Tortoise. 
Проблема. Делала checkout одного файла и по ошибку указала путь как D:. То есть просто диск D. Сheckout для файла выполнился, но теперь все файлы, которые были на диске отмечены знаком вопроса SVN. Как это исправить? То есть нужно, чтобы он прекратил вообще слежение (или как это правильно называется) за диском D. На диске куча важных файлов.

Comment: все очень просто найдите каким-то файловым менеджером все скрытые папки .svn и удалите их (кроме тех которые вам нужны). если у вас свн лежит в `D:\work\svn` значит в этой папке ничего трогать не стоит (включяя все вложенные)

Comment: Не совсем понимаю) По вашей логике мне нужно удалить весь диск D. Потому что у него у самого диска стоит зелёная галочка, а на всех (вообще на всех-всех-всех) файлах внутри - знак вопроса.

Comment: @Believe farytale, речь о скрытых папках .svn

На сколько я знаю, последние версии SVN создают одну папку .svn в корне проекта, поэтому если вы сделали чекаут в корень D, то вкключите отображение скрытых файлов, найдите папку d:\.svn и удалите ее. Старые версии SVN создавали эти скрытые папки во всех подпапках.

В директории .svn содержится вся сервисная информация по репозиторию

Comment: Спасибо большое) Всё получилось. Вы меня прям спасли)

Answer (score 1):

При команде `checkout` SVN создает в целевой папке свою собственную папку с именем `.svn`. Чтобы отменить действие `checkout`, нужно вручную найти и удалить эту папку.

Папка `.svn` является скрытой. Если ее не видно, то нужно включить отображение скрытых файлов.

Старые версии SVN создавали папку .svn в каждой подпапке. Если вы используете версию, выпущенную как минимум до 12 марта 2014, то проверьте какую-нибудь из подпапок.